# How To Fetch Subcollection In the Same Read As Parent Collection (Or restructure data?)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 app using Firebase auth and Firestore to record the outcomes of Mario Kart races. This is just a fun side project to get to know Vue and Firebase better.

I am new to none relational databases having used primarily MySQL/MariaDb and MSSQL in the past.

I have a parent collection called "games" with fields for various game settings values and a subcollection called "players" to record the score and place of each player in the cup.

`getDocs(collection(db, "games"))` returns all the "games" records but the "players" subcollections are not loaded.

Is there a way to have the subcollection returned with the parent collection or do I need to do a sub query, something like

```
getDocs(collection(db, "games")).then((response) => {
  response.forEach((doc) => {
    //do sub query here?
  });
});
```

If I need to do a sub query, why not just have "players" as a parent collection also with a "game_id" field pointing the the game record?

I've read through the Firestore docs and watched a couple videos on the different ways to structure data but it is just not clicking.

Sorry if this is a noob question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getDocs(collection(db, "games")) returns all the "games" records but the "players" subcollections are not loaded.

Yes, that's expected. Firestore's queries are *Shallow*, which means it will only get the collection you specified directly.
See:

[Firestore: Does querying a collection also includes their sub collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55632268/12349734)

> If I need to do a sub query, why not just have "players" as a parent collection also with a "game_id" field pointing the the game record?

Yes, you can definitely  do that.